# Get rid of whitespace in a pattern rule

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I have the following pattern rule:

```
static List<String> fetchUrls( String tweet ) {
     List<String> url = new ArrayList<String>();
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "(?:^|[\\W])((ht|f)tp(s?):\\/\\/|www\\.)" + "(([\\w\\-]+\\.){1,}?([\\w\\-.~]+\\/?)*" + "[\\p{Alnum}.,%_=?&#\\-+()\\[\\]\\*$~@!:/{};']*)");
     Matcher matcher = p.matcher( tweet );

     while ( matcher.find() ) {
         url.add( matcher.group() ); // When an URL is detected, we add it to the Array List
     }

     return url;
}
```

However, when I print a string representation of the `ArrayList`, I have a whitespace before the first url. How can I get rid of this whitespace?

Comment: trim the value if you dont want to change regex: url.add(matcher.group().trim())

Answer (score 0):

You may replace the `(?:^|[\W])` with `\b` since you are matching a start of string or a non-word char with that alternation group.

Since the next subpattern is `h`, the `\b` before it exactly matches a location at the beginning of the string or a non-word char.

If you want to keep using your pattern, it will look as

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "\\b((ht|f)tp(s?):\\/\\/|www\\.)" + "(([\\w\\-]+\\.){1,}?([\\w\\-.~]+\\/?)*" + "[\\p{Alnum}.,%_=?&#\\-+()\\[\\]\\*$~@!:/{};']*)");
                              ^^^
```

Now, `matcher.group()` should collect URLs without leading non-word chars.

You may get rid of unnecessary escaping backslashes and groups like

```
"\\b(?:(?:ht|f)tps?://|www\\.)" + 
"(?:(?:[\\w-]+\\.)+?(?:[\\w.~-]+/?)*" + 
"[\\p{Alnum}.,%_=?&#+()\\[\\]*$~@!:/{};'-]*)"
```